# Write a custom redirect for asp.net that parses the url and check if url contains a string in a string array length = 1000

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, azure

I am have an ASP.NET website, actually Umbraco, but don't think that relates to my question at all, and a related Wordpress blog.

The Wordpress blog used to be the parent website so all the urls are in the following format:

```
mywebsite.com/my-seo-powerful-blog-post
```

I have moved the blog to blog.mywebsite.com so the new url will be:

```
blog.mywebsite.com/my-seo-powerful-blog-post
```

So all the old seo url mappings will be hitting the new asp.net website at

```
mywebsite.com
```

There I would like to parse every request and do something like:

```
var oldBlogPosts = new List<string>()
     { "my-seo-powerful-blog-post",
       "my-other-seo-powerful-blog-post",
       ...and so, for 960 existings blog posts
     }

 if(oldBlogPosts.Any(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Contains)
      Response.Redirect("blog.mywebsite.com/" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments[1]);
```

I am hosting on Azure, not that that matters. I could build an HttpHandler and add it to my web.config but not sure Azure does HttpHandlers simply, I see people having errors deploying custom HttpHandlers to Azure.

I could more easily add this to the masterpage OnPageInit for every request. I would assume this code would not be a performance impact but I am not sure.

**Is there any speed improvements with my plan of attack if I just add my code to my Masterpage code behind versus creating a new HttpHandler?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put the redirect mappings into your web.config: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

But if you're going to do it in code, why wouldn't you just do something like this in global.asax and have done with it?

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
  int    n            = Request.Url.Segments.Length ;
  string postId       = n > 0 ? Request.Url.Segments[n-1] : null ;
  bool   isOldRequest = postId != null && RedirectablePaths.Contains(postId) ;

  if ( isOldRequest )
  {
    UriBuilder destination = new UriBuilder( Request.Url ) ;

    destination.Host = "blog." + Request.Url.Host ;

    Response.RedirectPermanent( destination.Uri.AbsoluteUri ) ;
  }

  return ;
}
private static readonly string[] OldBlogPosts = {
  "my-seo-powerful-blog-post",
  "my-other-seo-powerful-blog-post",
  // ...and so, for 960 existings blog posts
  } ;
private static readonly HashSet<string> RedirectablePaths = new HashSet<string>( OldBlogPosts , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ;
```

**Edited to note:** The reasons for using something like `HashSet<T>` or `SortedSet<T>` here

- **Semantics.** You have a *set* here — a unique collection of objects (as opposed to a *bag*, a collection of objects that allows duplicates and is not necessarily unique) — and you are concerned with set operations: whether or not something is a member of that set.
- **Performance.** `List<T>` is fundamentally an array (not a linked list, its name notwithstanding). Either way, An operation like `Enumerable.Any()` is an iteration over the collection and runs in O(n) time. That means the the run time is linearly proportional to the size of the data. For `Any()` to succeed it will take, on the average, n/2 operations to find an item in the set; for `Any()` to fail, it will require n operations, since it can't fail until its examined everything in the list.

  - `HashSet<T>` is a hash table and assuming a reasonable hashing function, lookups in the hash table run in O(1) time, meaning that any lookup, whether it succeeds or fails takes [relatively] constant time.
  - `SortedSet<T>` is an alternative set data structure. Under the covers, it is a [*red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), a  particular type of height-balanced binary tree. A search in a red-black tree is an O(log n) operation, meaning it's proportional to the logarithm of the data set size.

  Since a red-black tree is a binary tree, it's an O(log<sub>2</sub> n) operation to be precise, and therefore proportional to the depth of the tree.

So, if you have a big set, say, of 4.2 billion items,

- Stored in a `List<T>`, an operation like `Any()` will take, on the average 2.1 billion comparisons to succeed and return true and 4.2 billion comparisons to fail and return false.
- Stored in a `SortedSet<T>`, that equivalent `Contains()` operation will, in the worst case (item not found), require c. 32 comparisons — plus/minus a few, since red-black trees aren't perfectly balanced — to find (or not find) an item.
- Stored in a `HashSet<T>`, the lookup will run in O(1) [relatively] constant time, but whether that is faster than the `SortedSet<T>`'s O(log n) time or not is is dependent on several factors, including:

  - complexity of the hash function (cost of computing the hash value)
  - quality of the computed hash value (how perfectly random is it?)
  - number of buckets in the hash table
  - number of objects per bucket.

Comment: Beautiful and exactly why I asked the question, for better ways ;), of course I should just put it in the global.asax. Why didn't I think of that ;). Is the HashSet more performant than a List<string> with Linq query? Or just a datatype you prefer for its StringComparer options that you can pass in?

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help Nicholas, very kind of you, hope I can return the favor in the future